# Different text file for each language

Tags: android

I set the configuration shown in [this link](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html) for multi languages. I have the following folder order :

```
MyProject/
    res/
       values/
           strings.xml
       values-fr/
           strings.xml
```

I would like to set a specific txt file for each languages. Something looking like that :

```
MyProject/
        res/
           values/
               strings.xml
               words.txt //content in english
           values-fr/
               strings.xml
               words.txt //content in french
```

Is it possible, and is it possible for me to retrieve the content of this files with something like that ?

```
String content = getResources().getString(R.words);
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that? The reason for having a strings.xml-File is exactly the fact that you do not need another file for your strings... Or maybe you can tell us what the words.txt file contains? However, I'd suggest you move the content of your words.txt completely into the respective strings.xml.

Comment: It's an "Hangman" game with words saved localy depends on language. Dont interested about all this SqlLite stuff.

Comment: Then consider using the strings.xml file. Every resource should have an integer as identifier, so you could build upon that to randomly select a word from the strings.xml-file, probably... just as an idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends if you really want to save plain text file (as you suggested by `words.txt` name). If not, then maybe convert your words into normal string resource file and then you got things done.

If you cannot use resource file, then put your files in `assets/` folder and name them `words.txt`, `words-fr.txt`. Then knowing what language you are using now, you can oper correct file.

Comment: If it possible to put in the `strings.xml` file large amount of data. For example a string 13k+ caracters long ?

Comment: Sure it is but you are also not limited to single `strings.xml` file in your project. You can split your string resources among many files - so you can safely stick to `words.xml` -> this will be merged into `R.strings.` during build so no worries